# GCP can a cloud function auto create a PubSub topic?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I have a GCP Cloud Function publishing events into an output PubSub topic. If I have the output topic pre-created - all is fine.
However, I'd like to have the Cloud Function to auto create the topic if it does not already exist. Is it possible?

I have this code for publishing:

```py
publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
data = json.dumps(event).encode("utf-8")
topic_path = publisher.topic_path(project, topic)
publisher.publish(topic_path, data)
```

I know I could add a call to create the topic first:

```py
topic = publisher.create_topic(request={"name": topic_path})
```

and catch an exception if it tires to create an existing topic
but this sounds more like a dirty hack to me, not to mention unnecessary call to the publisher API and wasted cycles handling the call and exceptions on every CF invocation ....

Thank you!

Comment: You can do that only once, at function startup. You will waste time only once, not on each publish. Put it out of the Cloud Functions entrypoint. Share more of your code if you need more guidance

Comment: Why do need to create the topic the first time in the `Cloud Function` ? Is it not better for you to delegate this responsability outside of the `Cloud Function` ? example with a Infra As Code Tool like `Terraform` or if it's not possible a dedicated script.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere yes, that's a good idea - better than doing the try/fail on each invocation - thank you!

Comment: @MazlumTosun - yea, you are right, but we are just trying to minimize the number of moving parts ...